# How to find the current and voltage of this circuit?

Tags: voltage, current, diodes

I have this circuit with a Z-Diode in reverse.
Find U2 and I2?

I solved the fist circuit.

- U1 = 0.7V,  I1 = (15V-0.7V)/1kΩ)= 14.3mA

The results for are U2-8.2V  I2=6.8mA but I just can't figure out how to come to that

[image]

Comment: Your problem can't be solved with the information you have provided. You must be given either I2 or U2. Please post the question exactly as asked. This looks like homework so you need to show some effort at a solution to prevent your question being closed as off-topic as we don't offer a free homework service. Use the edit link below your question.

Comment: Homework with no attempt at a solution

Comment: No its not homework. I just  found these exercises and I can seem to solve this part

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Where did you get the information that the forward voltage drop of the zenner diode (U1) is 0.7V? It is a pretty reasonable assumption for any normal silicon diode including the other diodes, but not stated in your question.

Comment: There's nothing that gives the breakdown voltage (directly or with calculations) of ZD. As long as you hide something this is unsolvable.

Answer (score 0):

Your knows are:

- V<sub>S</sub> = 15 V.
- R<sub>2</sub> = 1 kΩ.

Your unknowns are:

- I<sub>2</sub>.
- V<sub>ZD</sub>.
- U<sub>2</sub> (which should be the same as V<sub>ZD</sub>.

If that's all the information you have been given then you can only solve for U<sub>2</sub> and I<sub>2</sub> in terms of V<sub>ZD</sub>. You won't be able to give a numerical answer as in the case of U<sub>1</sub> and I<sub>1</sub>.

Are you sure that you have supplied all the information given?

Comment: Managed to solve it a but. you can check my edited question

Comment: Your edited question doesn't show your solution and still doesn't provide the missing information.

Comment: I figured it out the VZD=8.2V , kowing that I easily solved the problem

Comment: If you are saying that you were told that it was an 8.2 V Zener then you need to add that into the question. If not, then how did you figure it out?

Comment: I added into the equation and  then I was able to figure out I2 and U2